# Keep default grid cell style when using Gridcolumn celltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I added some animation to gridcontrol cell. And by doing this I'm forced to specify a control to bind the data to, e.g.:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="ChangedAnimation">
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="name"
                                                    From="Transparent" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </DataTemplate.Resources>

                            <dxe:TextEdit Style="{StaticResource TextCellStyle}" Name="name" Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Name, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}"  BorderThickness="0"></dxe:TextEdit>

                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.NameChanged}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ChangedAnimation}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>

                </dxg:GridColumn>

                .... more gridcolumns ...

</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

Unfortunately this creates spacing between the cells. Not only does it look nasty, the user can click on the text field and update the field. Also, it makes it difficult to right click and show menu items i.e. you have to click *in between* the cells, and I don't want it. 
I would like to be able to keep the default GridControl look,where you have to click twice to allow edit and without the horrid cell spacing.

Instead of using textedit what can I use? TextBlock or Label doesn't  work.

Comment: Try to change your `TextEdit` name from `name` to `PART_Editor`.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc That got the default view back. But when I click on it, the text disappears and I can't fill it in the data.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc Your tip helped me figure it out. Thanks!